# Facebook Conversion Tracking Pixel in Ajax Application

Tags: ajax, facebook

Running into a facebook tracking issue. When a user creates an account, I want to fire off the FB tracking pixel.

When the landing page went live, only 1/2 of the new users are tracked. Any ideas on where the leaking issue is?

```
pp.onNewUser = function(v,u) {
    // Set Facebook Tracking
    var fb_param = {};
    fb_param.pixel_id = '43211230943123';
    fb_param.value = '0.00';
    fb_param.currency = 'USD';
    var fpw = document.createElement('script');
    fpw.async = true;
    fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
    var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
    try {
     console.log('Account Created...');
    } catch(ex) {}
    pp.aCN('step1a', 'hidden');
    pp.rCN('step2b', 'hidden');

};
```

Answer (score -1):

First I'd recommend upgrading to the new version of the code.  There's a guide here:

[Facebook: Migrate to the New Conversion Pixel](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/conversion-pixel-code-migration#jscode)

Or you can use the dropdown in adsmanager to generate it. There is also information on firing multiple events, for example: website custom audience and a conversion event.